# How to dynamically load the cron expression for @scheduled annotation from an externally configurable property file

Tags: java, spring

I need to load the cron expression for @scheduled annotation dynamically from a property file.
I know the solution for this would be using property place holder, but my problem is that, property file which contains the cron expression can be modified dynamically and its location is derived from another property file.

application-context.xml looks something like this,

```
    <util:properties id="dynamicProps" location="${configurable.property.file.path}"
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="dynamicProps"  />
```

configurable.property.file.path property is present in a property file that is located under WEB-INF/classes and the value of this is something like this,

```
 configurable.property.file.path=${static.assets.path}/config/configuration.properties
```

With the above settings on start up server cribs with the following error,

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dynamicProps' while setting bean property 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamicProps': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/${configurable.property.file}]
```

I am guessing the reason for this may be that property files are not yet visible at this point. What is the solution for this? Could someone pl help me on this?

Comment: Did you find answer to this?